# Why is there a note on my boot?

Tags: word-choice, etymology

Today I was reading [an article in *The Register*](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/06/22/canadian_sniper_3450m_shot_iraq/), and I noticed this unusual usage:

[image: screencap of Register article showing header "bootnote"]

I've never seen a *footnote* called a *bootnote* before.

The [OED doesn't list it](http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=Bootnote&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch), and using OneLook to search over a hundred dictionaries [only results in 4 hits](http://onelook.com/?w=Bootnote&ls=a), 3 of which redirect, without comment, to *footnote*, and one which is a false positive¹. Etymonline likewise [comes up dry](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bootnote).

Lest anyone jump the gun, this usage is intentional, not a typo, at least in the case of *The Register*, as Josh and Chris point out in the comments. And while both the [BNC](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/?c=bnc&q=57453649) and [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=57453641) corpora find no hits, [nor Google nGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bootnote&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), the [GLoWBE comes back with a few](https://www.english-corpora.org/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=57453822), suggesting that the usage is probably does not predate the internet, but is seeing growth and adoption on it, at least among BrE speakers<sup>**bn**</sup>.

[image: screencap of GLoWBE results for bootnote]

Morphologically, it makes sense: a *boot*, like a foot, comes at the bottom. But whence this usage?

Who uses it, and when is it used in preference for the more common *footnote*? Is it merely a Register thing? A broader BrE thing²?

What are its origins? Who used it first, and when? Do we know why? Simply a more colorful or cutesy synonym for *footnote*?  Originally a serendipitous, one-letter typographical error for *footnote*, which happened to make sense and stuck?

Are there any publications which use both *footnote* and *bootnote*? If so, what are the nuances between them? Is it something as silly as a *bootnote* goes "over" a *footnote* as a *boot* goes "over" a *foot*?

---

¹ <sub>To the Wordnik, which usually captures unusual words with more flavor, simply says "no entry" and notes the word has only been looked up ~200 times.</sub>

² <sub>There's an identical usage in [the Geekzone](https://www.geekzone.co.nz/foobar/6229), which has a `.nz` TLD, so presumably the writer speaks AusE, which hews relatively close to BrE. But there's no way of knowing if this particular non-Register usage was influenced by The Register, or indeed if it's an innocent typo. But it's evidence of use outside The Register either way.</sub>

<sub>**BOOTNOTE**: To be fair, I haven't actually dug into any of those citations to determine if they are all, in fact, from the Register itself.</sub>

Comment: Looks like it is a term of thier own : http://www.theregister.co.uk/Profile/bootnote_the_land_of_the_free_ha/ - https://www.theregister.co.uk/bootnotes/

Comment: It is in fact a fascinating question, but 'bootnote' at first glance looks suspiciously like a typo for footnote, which might explain its rarity and the paucity of definitions. However, since the Register seems to have used it on multiple pages, it might well be a special term they coined, or even an in-house joke/ euphemism!

Comment: as @EnglishStudent says, it's a house term based on *footnote*, which they often use for "and finally" type stories.  *The Register*'s style is idiosyncratic, as you'll see if you look at some of their headlines and subheadings.

Comment: @EnglishStudent The [GLoWBE corpus has quite a few hits](http://corpus.byu.edu/glowbe/) for it. I haven't dug any deeper into the individual cites (e.g. to see if all of them are from *The Register*, or are innocent typos, etc), but one thing is clear from the first column of the results table; they're all in BrE (which makes sense to me, aesthetically; I feel like Brits are more likely to employ this variety of wordplay, and they use *boot* more often, as in *jackbooted* and the trunk of a car). COCA, BNC, and Google nGrams didn't find it, so this is def. an Internet age thing.

Comment: @ChrisH Sounds like you know whereof you speak! If you can find some kind of support on the Registers site which says more or les the, I'd accept it as an answer. More exciting would be their sorry about how it came about, and why they built it into their house style.

Comment: Do you think it has the potential to become a wider used term online?

Comment: The register used is idiosyncratic (Doing some quick'n'dirty exterior ballistics calculations  ...  extreme long range small arms ballistics is a bit of a hit-or-miss affair (ho ho) ) so one might expect some deviations from standard English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sure, but I'm looking for the logic behind the (intentional) deviations.  Or a statement from The Register on the history of choosing this word. EnglishStudent: [It's difficult to make predictions, especially about the future](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/10/20/no-predict/).

Comment: You need to contact the people who came up with this then; I'd better close-vote as not addressing standard English usage now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it almost certainly is not addressing acceptable usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Establishing whether or not it is standard English is one of the goals of this question (*viz*, "Who uses it, and when is it used in preference for the more common footnote? Is it merely a Register thing? A broader BrE thing?"). You are asserting it via a close-vote, but the proper place to assert it -- with evidence -- is in an answer. I have shown evidence from the GLoWBE that it is used.

Comment: We've had far more persuasive evidence that grammatical howlers are in common use. The negative evidence you yourself supply in the 'question' would surely be regarded by most as sufficient for a 'non-standard' labelling.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Regardless of whether this is a "howler" or not (in my view, it's merely precious, in the old-school "cutesy" sense), the job of *determining* that is an answer. A question is not off-topic merely because the answer is "no".  Also there are uses in the wild outside the Register, like in [the GeekZone](https://www.geekzone.co.nz/foobar/6229), so this is not a Register-only usage.

Comment: @DanBron I've put together what I know/can find out in a few minutes.  There's an element of the in-joke, or if not exactly *joke* then jargon marking an in-group.  I suspect it's deliberately hard to pin down.

Comment: Given the irreverent tone of The Register, bootnote might come from the sense of boot:  *6.
Slang. a dismissal; discharge*,  and from the obvious assonance with foot.

Comment: If I were to VTC, it'd be because of the title. *When and where is 'bootnote' used in preference for the more common 'footnote'?* Apparently, at *The Register*. If you're going to use click bait titles, it'd better be summarily ontopic.

Comment: A couple of things I don't want to clutter my answer with: **1** All the GLoWBE hits are from *The Register* except 3; of those one is the personal site of a *Register* writer.  **2** some dictionaries seem to list as a redirect for footnote; this may be typo detection, or it may be an element of crowdsourcing (wikipedia redirects *bootnote* to *note (typography)* with no further explanation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bootnotes** is a term commonly used by *The Register* (a UK-based IT news website). The whole website aims for an irreverent tone (see especially the subtitles, and any headline they can get away with turning into a suggestive pun).

They apply *bootnote* to stories which are a bit of light relief, and only tangentially (at best) related to IT, i.e. the sort of stories that would be *and finally...* on TV news. *Bootnote* can also be used as a direct synonym for *footnote* when applied to addenda to the articles that are their real work [(e.g. US Navy plans self-building floating fortresses)](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/03/24/self_assembly_floating_fortresses/?page=4).

Sometimes these stories are [reenacted using Playmobil](https://www.theregister.co.uk/bootnotes/playmobil/); the subtitle for the page collecting such reenactments is

> Welcome indeed to El Reg's world-beating miniature coverage of the stories that really matter - and quite a few that really don't, to be honest...

From their own website: [No sense of humour? Avoid Bootnotes
-- Fridays: A warning from history](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2008/04/11/bootnotes_advice/)

Etymologically, it would appear to be derived from a combination of *footnote* and perhaps *put the boot in* (i.e. kick, and a phrase they use fairly often, usually metaphorically) but they don't appear to have described it exactly at any point.  They're also rather fond of *jackboot* as a symbol of force, whether applied to the authorities or to Microsoft. Any relationship between *bootnote* and *boot* in the IT sense is probably about as coincidental as the relationship between IT and most of the material earning this tag.

Other (mainly tech and related) sites also use it, often in humorous or tongue-in-cheek posts, for example:

- [Slashdot comments](https://science.slashdot.org/story/05/08/08/222245/quantum-information-can-be-negative) (Slashdot has a readership that overlaps with The Register)
- [Geekzone.co.nz](https://www.geekzone.co.nz/foobar/6229) (presuambly New Zealand-based)
- [Pistonheads.com](https://www.pistonheads.com/gassing/topic.asp?h=0&f=10&t=1218533&i=40&mid=0&nmt=EU+Gender+Directive)
- A [Google *groups* search](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!search/%22bootnote%22) shows sporadic use back to about 2000 (quotes are necessary to suppress hits like "...boot. Note...". Interestingly the plural form, unlike the singular, seems almost always to refer to El Reg)
- More recently searching Twitter suggests it's current, but again many hits are quoting *The Register*.

Almost all the results for which I can get clear indications of the writer's nationality are British, the rest Commonwealth (1 NZ, 1 Aus)

There are also independent uses, of which this is the most obvious:

- ["Bootnote is a plugin for Dokuwiki. It display some note inside the wiki with bootstrap style.[sic]"](https://github.com/algorys/bootnote)

The earliest use I can find on *the Register* is from 2000: [Mad Cow toys removed from shelves](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2000/10/31/mad_cow_toys_removed/) (apparent earlier hits seem to be dodgy dates as the predate the publication or even the internet).  However an earlier reference from the (UK) [Naval Review](http://www.naval-review.com/issues/1990s/1991-4.pdf) (October 1991, p76) is worth quoting:

> A Bootnote From:
>
> Brigadier C. Bootstrop,
>
> Office of the Fleet
>
> Flag Officer
>
> Royal Marines
>
> The Old Sail Loft
>
> Southmouth-by-the-Sea
>
> I September 1995
>
> DEAR Shoot-Through, I was most impressed with your lofty broom cupboard at Canary Wharf and must thank you for the splendid and novel Boil-in-the-Bag lunch in the Directors' Self Help Canteen

as it takes a similar tone.  This may also hint at the etymology, as *bootneck* (or *bootie* but apparently not *boot*) is a slang term for a Royal Marine. In fact Lewis Page, editor/defence correspondent at *the Register*, and a frequent user of the term, has a naval background.

Comment: @DanBron there's more...

Comment: This isn't about the English language in general but about the peculiar non-standard usages of one specific publication. And as such, off-topic.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I can't upvote you more than once, and Edwin has cancelled that out, but I can accept the answer when the deadline passes. Might even offer a bounty on the Q (which I could award to you, unless I'd be compelled to award to someone else who one-upped you, which I doubt will happen).

Comment: Also that Navy quote is *fantastic*!

Comment: I may have a little more to add; that last edit was made in haste.

Comment: With the permission of OP @Dan Bron, you could quote and include the linux reference in the GeekZone (supplied by OP in a comment) in this answer to make it categorical that at least 3 different sources have used 'bootnote' in print / online publication and it was not used by the Register alone. You should hurry because apparently any comment can be deleted anytime by a competent authority, including but not restricted to OP!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth your vote is of course yours, but *usage* is on topic; establishing that the use of a certain word is less niche, less jargon than initially thought is a good fit here.

Comment: @EnglishStudent Chris certainly doesn't need my permission, but he can unquestionably has it.  He can add the link from footnote #2 of my question, above the "bootnote". There's also [this car enthusiast forum post by mrmr96](https://www.pistonheads.com/gassing/topic.asp?h=0&f=10&t=1218533&i=40&mid=0&nmt=EU+Gender+Directive) and [this blog](http://andreworlowski.com/2009/01/19/why-animals-shouldnt-be-able-to-sue-you/) where the word is used unselfconsiously.

Comment: @Dan Bron those links would be more useful in the answer of Chris H, in my opinion, by presenting wider use of the term than just in one publication; and I was simply urging the chivalrous member not to be deterred *in good taste* by your first use of the reference in your question!

Comment: @EnglishStudent Ah, understood. Yes, agreed these links would be better in an answer. Chris also mentioned he may have more edits up his sleeve, which I'm enthusiastically awaiting.

Comment: Thanks @DanBron, that was the edit that I was thinking of. But I've got some more digging in mind

Comment: @Dan Bron And in the last resort, there is nothing stopping you from comprehensively answering your own question (as I did twice myself) *with adequate citations!* Since the site prefers the scholarly treatment, better go all the way, if you feel it is indicated.

Comment: @EnglishStudent No way I'm going to try to compete with this answer :)

Comment: @Dan Bron, if Chris H will use all those references, you will not need to compete with that excellent answer.

Comment: Wonderful, comprehensive answer. Thank you so much.